# Can an answer to a question which has been put on hold be marked as accepted?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, on-hold

I answered a question, and the question was then put on hold. Can the asker mark the answer as accepted even though the question is on hold?

Comment: That's possible yes.

Comment: That being said, you should try to put your efforts into answering on-topic questions. Much more likely to succeed that way.

Comment: Understandable, if I'm striving for reputation alone. I also wanted to help make someone's day be that little bit easier :)

Comment: [Over 300K](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=closed%3A1+hasaccepted%3A1&mixed=0) of such questions.

Comment: @rene I thought I'd clarify though as those questions could have been closed after the answer was marked as complete.

Comment: Fair enough: [85528](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/919871) such questions as of last sunday.

Comment: Wow, I had no idea you could query StackExchange with SQL syntax. Thanks!

Comment: You might like the [tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) in that case.

Comment: @markmoxx *"I also wanted to help make someone's day be that little bit easier :)"* - That's fine, just keep in mind this site has strict rules and they apply to nice guys too ;)

Comment: @markmoxx Info: Telling OP how to ask good questions, make a MCVE, debug their program and do proper research would be more helpful to OP on the long term.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A question being marked on hold (closed) does not prevent answers from being marked as accepted.

All that closing a question does is prevent more answers being posted. A closed question can also be [automatically deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) under specific circumstances.